# Redirection with PHP or .htaccess - which is better for SEO?

Tags: php, htaccess, seo

I need one practical advice - is better to redirect with .htaccess Redirect 301 rules, or to use PHP header function (after parsing URL)?

Which one is better to Google and SEO?

Tnx in adv!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HTTP clients cannot tell what caused a server to return a 30x redirect status, so it makes absolutely no difference.

Comment: Ok for HTTP clients, but what about search engine spiders?

Comment: Search engine spiders **are** HTTP clients (except the one used for Mystic Meg's Special Search Engine, which reads the minds of the content authors instead).